# Como puedo dejar funcional un datepicker de bootstrap pero readonly

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, datepicker

Tengo un input definido de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="text" name="fecha" id="datepicker" pattern="[_0-9]{2}/[_0-9]{2}/[_0-9]{4}" class="form-control" required>
```

Con el siguiente script en la misma pagina

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "es",
    autoclose: true,
    startView: 2,
    endDate: "+Infinity"
});
</script>
```

Lo que necesito es que no se puedo ingresar mediante teclado la fecha sino que simplemente se escoja desde el datepicker. El disable me apaga el componente directamente.

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colócale el atributo `readonly` al input para que quede en modo solo lectura.

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "es",
    autoclose: true,
    startView: 2,
    endDate: "+Infinity"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="#">
<input type="text" name="fecha" id="datepicker" pattern="[_0-9]{2}/[_0-9]{2}/[_0-9]{4}" class="form-control" required readonly>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Excelente lo pruebo, sumamente simple.

Comment: Impecable Juan, lo probé y anda muy bien.

Comment: @CarlosCristoforone Me alegra saberlo, si te fue útil la respuesta marcala como solución a tu pregunta así mejoran las estadísticas del sitio, y otros usuarios pueden encontrarla útil.

Comment: Juan, marcarla como respuesta es ponerle flechita arriba no? Traté, pero como soy nuevo no tengo suficiente reputación y no me deja.

Comment: @CarlosCristoforone para marcarla como solucionada, dale click al check que aparece debajo de la cantidad de votos

Comment: Ahh, gracias, ya lo marque.

Answer (score 0):

Detén el evento por defecto (`e.preventDefault()`) y la propagación (`e.stopPropagation()`) en el evento `click` del `.day` del datepicker.

```js
$('#fecha-nac').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
  }).on('show', (e) => {
    $('.day').click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```css
.group {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
}
label {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- css -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" />

<div class="group">
<label for="fecha-nac">Fecha Nac.</label> <input type="text" id="fecha-nac" class="form-control" value="29/06/2016"  readonly="readonly"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, había visto esta solución pero no me parecía muy elegante.

Comment: Hola @CarlosCristoforone ya funciono tu script? sería interesante saber que respuesta es la que eliges para futuras preguntas.

Comment: Probe la otra y anduvo muy bien.